# How to create two triggers for the same object

Tags: triggers, apex, apex-code, lwc

I have a data table where if a client selects multiple candidates it will automatically create a Job Application AND a Review record. I made a trigger for the creation of a review record but the problem is there is also another requirement where the Interviewer of the Job Application should be inserted in the review record. I am trying to create two triggers that will fire on the Job application object but I have not tried to do two triggers in one object before and I'm stuck.

The idea is IF I edit the Interview field on the Job Application the Interview field on the Review object would also be updated.

```
trigger JobApplicationTrigger on Job_Application__c (after insert) {
    if (Trigger.isAfter) {
        if(Trigger.isInsert) {
            List<Review__c> reviewList = new List<Review__c>();
    
                for(Job_Application__c jobApp : trigger.new) {
                    //review records should only contain  Interviewer and Job Application. SELECT Interviewer__c, Name FROM Job_Application__c
        
                    //create review records
                    Review__c newRev = new Review__c();
                    newRev.Interviewer__c = jobapp.Interviewer__c;
                    newRev.Job_Application__c = jobApp.Id;
                    reviewList.add(newRev);
                }
    
    
                if (reviewList.size() > 0) {
                    insert reviewList;
                }
        }   


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your last statement *'The idea is IF I edit the Interview field on the Job Application the Interview field on the Review object would also be updated.'*
you don't have to create a new trigger for this. You can use the existing one.

The following snippet will help you.

```
trigger JobApplicationTrigger on Job_Application__c(after insert, after update) {
  if (Trigger.isAfter) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert) {
      List<Review__c> reviewList = new List<Review__c>();

      for (Job_Application__c jobApp : Trigger.new) {
        //review records should only contain  Interviewer and Job Application. SELECT Interviewer__c, Name FROM Job_Application__c

        //create review records
        Review__c newRev = new Review__c();
        newRev.Interviewer__c = jobapp.Interviewer__c;
        newRev.Job_Application__c = jobApp.Id;
        reviewList.add(newRev);
      }

      if (reviewList.size() > 0) {
        insert reviewList;
      }
    }
    // New Code
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
      List<Review__c> reviewList = new List<Review__c>();

      for (Job_Application__c jobApp : Trigger.new) {
      //create review records if value of Interviewer__c is changed on Job_Application__c
        if(jobapp.Interviewer__c!=Trigger.oldMap(jobApp.Id.Interviewer__c)){
          Review__c newRev = new Review__c();
          newRev.Interviewer__c = jobapp.Interviewer__c;
          newRev.Job_Application__c = jobApp.Id;
          reviewList.add(newRev);
        }
      }

      if (reviewList.size() > 0) {
        // update exising review records
        update reviewList;
      }
    }
  }
}
```